# How to count line crosses between horizontal line and tree line dendogram python

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am making program how to count the best number of cluster on hierarchical clustering, number of cluster is define by number of horizontal line that cross vertical line of tree

[image: dendogram]

how to count number of crosses line between horizontal line using axhline and tree line in dendogram? , here is my script to visualize but i dont know how to count number of crosses

```
plt.figure(0)
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 7))
plt.title("Customer Dendograms")
L=shc.linkage(X, method='average')
dend = shc.dendrogram(L)
plt.axhline(c=c,linestyle='--', y=35) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is not something that can be solved graphically using matplotlib, so I removed that tag. You need to figure out the format of the *linkage matrix* `L` that is returned by the `linkage` function, maybe it is easy to get your answer from that. Alternatively, you can look at the source code of the `dendogram` function, which uses this information to make the plot, it should know the coordinates of all the lines it plots. You could modify that code so that it checks for all the vertical lines it plots if they cross the level you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly my field, so I am giving a try here.

Each line in the [linkage matrix Z](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage) is composed of: id of the merged clusters, distance between the two clusters and total number of elements in the new cluster.

The heights are assumed to be in ascending orders in the Z matrix (i.e. no [inversions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/83311/254719)?). Each time a cluster is formed (by merging two clusters) the number of cluster is decreased by one. So, the number of cluster corresponding to each line of the Z matrix, is equal to `nbr_of_leaves - idx of the line`.

The [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) function allows to get the line id given an arbitrary height. Then, the number of cluster for a given height is `nbr_of_leaves - np.digitize(height, Z[:, 2])`

Here is a test example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage

def get_number_of_clusters(height, Z):
    nbr_of_leaves = Z.shape[0] + 1
    merge_heights = Z[:, 2]
    nbr_of_clusters  = nbr_of_leaves - np.digitize(height, merge_heights)
    return nbr_of_clusters

# data for an example
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 11, 4.5, 8, 9, 4])
x_2d = x.reshape(-1, 1)
Z = linkage(x_2d, method='single')

#for method = 'single' 
print(get_number_of_clusters(2.1, Z)) # 2
print(get_number_of_clusters(1.5, Z)) # 4
print(get_number_of_clusters(0.5, Z)) # 7

# Dendrogram
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 2))
dendrogram(Z, labels=x);
plt.grid(axis='y'); plt.xlabel('leaves'); plt.ylabel('distances');
plt.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the number of clusters at the given height.

Unless your linkage has inversions, you can trivially read this off from the linkage matrix L.